# Loading a sidemenu into a DOM with Ionic2 and Angular2 Typescript

Tags: javascript, dom, typescript, angular, ionic2

Im having trouble encapsulating the sidemenu from the app.ts

**app.html:**

```
 <ion-menu [content]="content"></ion-menu>
 <ion-nav id="nav" [root]="rootPage" #content ></ion-nav>
```

**app.ts**

```
import {App, IonicApp,Page, Platform} from 'ionic-angular';
import {PageLogin} from './pages/login/login';


@App({
  templateUrl: 'build/app.html',
  config: {}
})

class MyApp {
  rootPage: any = PageLogin;

  constructor(private app: IonicApp, private platform: Platform) {
    this.initializeApp();
}

  initializeApp() {
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {

    });

  }
}
```

This will enable a side menu which i can drag and interact with but is yet still empty. I can put everything down in the app.html and write any code that i want executed in app.ts.

But i want to create my sidemenu in the **/pages** folder and load this content into the `<ion-menu>` DOM

**sidemenu.html**

```
<ion-toolbar>
        <ion-title>Menu</ion-title>
</ion-toolbar>
<ion-content>
    <ion-list>
        ...
    </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

**sidemenu.ts**

```
import {Page} from 'ionic-angular';

@Page({
  templateUrl: 'build/pages/sidemenu/sidemenu.html'
})

export class SideMenu{

  constructor() {}
}
```

How can i load a snippet of an HTML into a DOM file ?
Or is there another way in which i can seperate the sidemenu code from the app.ts?

Thanks in advance

Comment: But... your template from `MyApp` is `app.html` which has a `<ion-menu>` element. But the selector of your `MyApp` component already is `ion-menu`.. Anyways, search in the angular2 documentation for `dynamicComponentLoader`. Not entirely sure what you are trying to achieve, but perhaps that will help you

Comment: I removed the selector in my comment, i did not intent to post it. But yes, you are right. My template from MyApp is app.html and has a ion-menu. How can i load  the code from sidemenu into the ion-menu ?

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to write this code yourself.  Since I see that your app.ts file is missing the "this.pages" section, I imagine that you built your project with the command

```
ionic start MyProject --v2
```

Instead, run the command

```
ionic start MyProject tutorial --v2
```

The tutorial project has a side menu built in.